# which Desktop would i get after ugrade to 16.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity, xubuntu, xfce, 16.04

Currently i'm using ubuntu 14.04 with **xubuntu-desktop**.

i had completely remove **unity** from my system.

now i want to upgrade my 14.04 to 16.04 so my question will i get **unity**  back or it will have upgraded **xubuntu-desktop**

Im upgrading referencing [this](http://www.ostechnix.com/upgrade-ubuntu-16-04-lts-final-beta/)  article

Comment: You get whatever Desktop Environment you had installed.  Xubuntu in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not affect your desktop environment. You will keep whatever you have right now, same as when you do a regular upgrade.

Comment: will it remove my data from '/home' ?